# How do you save an Excel file with multiple sheets as an RDS file for use in R?

Tags: r, excel

I am currently running an R function that uses XLConnect to scan a very large Excel file of many sheets, and I'm repeating this function 500 times.  It currently can take up to 20 minutes to run it, and I was told that I need to save it as an RDS to speed things up.  I'm an R beginner so what is an RDS, how do I save an Excel file as it, and once I do save it as an RDS, will I still be able to refer to the different sheets within the Excel file, or will I have to save each sheet as an RDS individually?

Answer (score -1):

At the prompt line of a running session of R type this:

```
?saveRDS
```

The questions about saving an Excel file and referring to different sheets have been answered many times in SO. You need to make some effort to look things up before posting multi-part questions.

Comment: I tried adding this this to the inside of function, instead of just using readWorksheetFromFile alone, but it didn't make it any faster: 
 sheet1 <- readWorksheetFromFile(document, sheet = char1, startRow = 2) 
  sheet2 <- readWorksheetFromFile(document, sheet = char2, startRow = 2) 
  
  saveRDS(sheet1, "sheet1.rds")
  read.sheet1 <- readRDS("sheet1.rds")
  
  saveRDS(sheet2, "sheet2.rds")
  read.sheet2 <- readRDS("sheet2.rds")

Comment: "didn't make it any faster" is not sufficient evidence of testing. You need to  present a complete problem with library calls and everything needed to perform a test, and then show proper benchmarking code taht isolates the read operation and present results.

Comment: This type of answer wastes space.

Comment: @tommylicious. Not any more than the question itself. If you wanted to edit the Q to include the code in the questioners comment and make it reproducible and then make the effort to work on a well stated task then by all means .. give it your best shot. Do make an effort to make the world a better place.